Is it possible to stop weeping between threaded copper joint on sprinkler system?
We just redid our sprinkler system last year and I found some weeping here when turning on the sprinklers for the summer. Is it possible to stop without having to take everything apart?

[

If it wasn't leaking last year, and is now, one possible cause is expansion of water stretched those fittings. Aside from any immediate repair, be sure  that the system is completely drained to below the frost line next fall, if there is any chance of freezing in your climate.

Only a note: check that it is weeping as it could be simply condensation. Cold metal parts in a humid weather will collect condensation.

If you really don't want to disassemble it, maybe solder. Probably will damage some of the internal seals, however.

Seems like soldering this would require disassembly anyway, with the PTFE tape on the threads.

You could try to wait out low flow rate seeping at joints on outside connections. At least with pipe dope seeping may finally plug from particulates in the water or the pipe dope. With PTFE tape alone it might take longer or maybe never stop seeping.

Those are both bronze (a copper alloy, not copper), and you'll have to disassemble enough to be able to tighten that. Or remove it, apply dope or tape, and tighten it.
Should not be "everything" but if you (or whoever built it) didn't put in enough unions to make it easily serviceable, it might be a lot. Or you can cut pipes and add unions to take apart less now, and make it more serviceable next time.
